# how to enable strict-transport-security in cloudfront using Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a cloudfront and back of it have couple APIGW's with Lambda Function configured. I want to enable strict-transport-security in cloudfront using Terraform. can someone please guide how to do it and do i need to enable it in cloudfront code or apigw code or Lambda code?

Iac code here i am using is Terraform.

Configuring it first time. So need code base.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PixarV/ritt/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_response_headers_policy#strict-transport-security) is the terraform resource you need to setup.

I also found [this blog post](https://devdosvid.blog/2021/11/05/apply-cloudfront-security-headers-with-terraform/) which looks like a good starting point about this as well that might help as well since this setup doesn't look super simple it might be good to see an example.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy" "headers_policy" {
  name = "security-headers-policy"
  security_headers_config {
    strict_transport_security {
      override = true
      access_control_max_age_sec = 63072000
      include_subdomains = true
      preload = true
    }
  }
}



resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "distribution" {
  aliases = 'alias'
  enabled = true

  default_cache_behavior {
    response_headers_policy_id = aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy.headers_policy.id
  }
}
```